# Inserting a figure in a SIAM template

Tags: graphics

I looked at a SIAM template example to understand how to insert a figure.  In this template, it codes:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\vspace{2.5in}
\caption{{\rm Log}$_{10}$ of the residual norm versus the number of
{\rm GMRES$(m)$} iterations for the finite difference methods.}
\label{diff}
\end{figure}
```

However, it never seems to indicate a specific file to upload the image.  A long time ago, i wrote a paper in the IEEE SIGS conference proceedings format, which used a command akin to:

```
\psfig{file=network_model.eps, height=2in, width=2in,}
```

inside the \begin{figure}...\end{figure} block.  I tried using it in my AMS paper, but it produces an undefined control sequence error.  What is the appropriate command to insert the figure from a local file?

**UPDATE:**  Sorry, I erroneously stated earlier that the template was from AMS, when it was truly from SIAM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want

```
\usepackage{graphicx}

...

\includegraphics[options]{myfile}
```

A detailed manual called [Using Imported Graphics in LATEX and pdfLATEX](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/epslatex) is freely available.