# What package do I need in order to use \psfig{...}?

Tags: graphics, postscript

I'm using `\documentclass[final]{siamltex}` to write a paper.  Within the document I'm trying to use a function \psfig.  I have used the following syntax successfully in other papers that I have previously written:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\psfig{file=myfile.eps, height=2in, width=2in,}
\caption{This is my caption.}
\end{figure}
```

However, when I use it in this file, I get an undefined control sequence error.
How do I fix it so that it will display my post-script images?  Do I need to use a special package?  Is there something wrong with my syntax?

Comment: You could use `epsfig` package but latex has had a standard graphics inclusion mechanism since latex2e in 1993, epsfig emulates the old psfig package for `\psfig` usage in latex 2.09 documents from the 1980's

Comment: is epsfig a package or a command?  if it's a package, what command do I use in it?

Comment: as I say it's a package (part of the core latex distribution) it supports the syntax you are using, but really why not use `\includegraphics` and the `graphicx` package (`epsfig` is just a thin wrapper that defines `\psfig` in terms of `\includegraphics`)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Mostly because... I'm a novice at LaTex, and didn't know better! :)  I'll try it out and see how it goes.

Comment: That's OK I just wonder how come a novice was given information that's 20 years out of date:-) use `\usepackage{graphicx}` in the preamble and `\includgraphics[height=2in,width=2in]{myfile}` to include the image.

Comment: @Paul: `psfig` is definitely not for the novice -- it's not free, and so won't be in your (la)tex distribution.  to use it, therefore, you have to learn about latex package installation.  put it behind you, and learn to swim in the tides of the 1990s (when psfig was superseded ;-)

Comment: I don't know much about LaTex... I just follow whatever templates i've worked with before, and \psfig is the only command i've seen (until today) for graphics:)  A standard google search gives me MORE information than I really need and it can be overwhelming to sort through it all (especially wit respect to LaTex).

Comment: Unfortunately the [SIAM Journal's LaTeX Template](http://www.siam.org/journals/auth-info.php) was not updated Since Nov 1996. Thats the state of many journals which dont keep pace with the LaTeX developement. You got a good reference for your [Question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86281/15717) here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax shown in the question is  provided by the `epsfig` package but this in only intended for compatibility for the `epsfig` and `psfig` packages for LaTeX2.09 it is not intended for any document produced this century.

The standard way to include graphics in LaTeX2e is

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

in the preamble and

```
\includegraphics[height=2in,width=2in, keepaspectratio]{myfile}
```

to include the image.